# Does code mandate outlets when windows are above the counter?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, kitchens, renovation

We are renovating our century home's kitchen and would like to install windows that go to the ceiling so that our marble backsplash does not have any seams in it. The thing we later realized is, if we have under cabinet outlets, there would be too much space between the outlet and the range (about 36 instead of the 24 stated in the code). Personally we are okay with this from a practical standpoint.

Since the window would make placing the outlet impossible, will this be okay from an inspection or will we be required to raise the window 3 inches to make room for the outlet (and by consequence introduce 4 new seams). It is my understanding that outlets placed facing up in the window sill would not be to code.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: Code or no code, you should have outlets closer to the stovetop than the far side of those windows.   If you want to use an immersion blender on the stovetop, or to use the stovetop as a convenient place to use a sous vide or electric grill .... you'll want to do these things without extension cords.  You may not use these machines but why design a new kitchen where it's impossible?

Comment: When there's no space on the wall you have to put the outlet on the surface of the countertop. But NEC states the maximum distance is 4 feet, not 2. You can also mount them sideways to get a few extra inches if space/measurements are really close.

Answer (score 1):

The area the range and sink occupy is not counted. But code shows 24” what I would do is put a tombstone receptacle in on each side of the stove counter top.

Some tombstones are quite nice I have used them in large islands and peninsular counters on multiple houses this may be the cleanest looking option as it will not affect the window and would not be below the counter.

Comment: Is that like those mocketts? I have seen that as suggestion on Houzz however I also dont like the idea of cutting into the countertop and wouldnt that also mean our cabinets would lose a few inches in the back?

Comment: No not a mocket those take up two much space.  I have single gang double gang and double gang double sided the granite ones I bought from the monument distributor it was spendy 300$. It may sound weird but the guys that cut head stones are very good with granite and have much better prices in my area. Look at armed.com/floor boxes/tombstone-floor-boxes, not bad price can be located in the back of the cabinet and only a 1/2” hole is needed to bring the 3/8 Mc conduit up. I have used these a few times , there is another place that makes them out of brass but I could not find them very similar.

Comment: thanks, is there a way you can post a photo? Not entire sure I understand the set up here

Comment: I don’t currently have 1 but they are set to the location you want within the 24” space I have used back to back so only the brushed brass was visible, I have also placed a single sided right up on the wall with the receptacle facing forward using the same granite that was used for the counter and drilled down the flange of a structural steel beam prevented going into the wall so we wrapped it in brass to not loose any wall space and made it an accent strip. With a brass tombstone in front. Most of them have been on islands that were not connected or peninsular that were long enough to require

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Ideally I would not want any holes in the countertop or the backsplash but if the metal part was hidden, that might be okay. https://www.housebeautiful.com/home-remodeling/a28260362/s-box-pop-up-outlet/ we would still loose a couple inches in the back

Comment: So the code would not be satisfied with two receptacles in the wall on the outsides of the windows? You must have a receptacle every 24 inches of the counter?! (The width of the range being excluded.)

Comment: That is much fancier but would reduce your drawer size, the type I was talking about are fixed . @jim stewart there has to be one within 24” of the sink then no space more than 48” apart similar to a room where the receptacles can be 12’ apart but no space more than 6’ apart. I just got called to go to a remote location but will try and find the style I have used.

Comment: @JimStewart yes this is my exact question

Comment: I would show this diagram to your local code inspector and show exactly where you want the receptacles. See what they say.